# Can we do a 32 bit encryption (AES256) in Mule

Tags: encryption, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have to do AES256 (32 bit key) encryption in mule. I am trying to use XML encryption available in Encryption component. Please help.

The picture for flow is attached. I am getting below error when I am using XML Encryptor.

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
ERROR 2016-11-08 16:19:37,913 [[testenc].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] 
Root Exception stack trace:
Root Exception stack trace:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
```

[image: Mule flow]

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work?  StackOverflow isn't a tutorial service.

Comment: @LukePark: I hope now you can quickly answer.

Comment: I have given a key whose length is 32 bits.

Comment: What is the payload of the flow? And what are you trying to encrypt from the payload? You can use an XML encryptor  for XML payloads only.

Comment: AES only uses keys of 128, 192 and 256 bits. I'm rather curious though how you encrypt users. My users aren't that easily mangled.

Comment: Do you mean 32 *bytes* (256 bits)?

Answer (score 0):

Exception : `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.` means  that your XML is either malformed or it contains white space before XML declarion in many case, check your XML first

`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the reference guide. You can configure the encryption in the visual editor by opening the Properties window

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.3/mule-message-encryption-processor